# Azure Data Factory :Get MetaData: Can filter the meta data by Folder Type and Pass the Folder Names to a For Loop

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Problem: Can we get the only the folder Names from a blob using meta data or any other activity. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BzZg.png)

I am trying to get the folder names and trying to use a filter with item type equals 'Folder', but the values include all the files present in the blob. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPDh4.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Filter activity after the Get Metadata.  Here is the JSON for one that filters to only files. 
 Change the filter below to just get files with this line: "value": "@equals(item().type, 'Folder')",

```
    {
        "name": "FilterFiles",
        "description": "Only files will be selected, the sub-folders will not be selected.",
        "type": "Filter",
        "dependsOn": [
            {
                "activity": "GetFileList",
                "dependencyConditions": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "userProperties": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "items": {
                "value": "@activity('GetFileList').output.childItems",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "condition": {
                "value": "@equals(item().type, 'File')",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response scott...we would just need the other way around ..get the Folder names only but not file names.

Comment: Then you just need to change the line where it does "@equals(item().type, 'File')" to be "@equals(item().type, 'Folder')" and it should give you what you want.